# resolving a clause. Resolved A and B yields

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, proof, clause

I was wondering why the following resolutions yield true and none rather than (A !D) and (A B C !D):

Resolve (A B C) & (!B !C !D) yields true
Resolve (A B C) & (B C !D) yields none.

Comment: Basic boolean logic: pls consult your notes

Comment: I did and I still don't understand so that's why I'm posting on a forum.

Comment: Nvm i figured it out